# Unity 2D - How to make Angry Birds Space Planet Physics?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

I have a some problems.

1) I want to make 2d planet exactlly like Angry Birds Space: same gravity, same force, same falling speed.

2) I don't know what gravity and force values should be.

3) When I add an object at the sides of the planet it falls to the bottom.

4) I want that when an object enters the gravity radius, it will stay at the radius and won't exit from the planet.

In sum: I want to make Angry Birds Space 2d planet exactlly like at the game.

short video of Angry Birds Space: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nH1tfaF7yRM.

That's the script:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(CircleCollider2D), typeof(CircleCollider2D))]
public class Planet : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float gravitation = 0.45f;

    public float gravitationRadius = 3.5f;

    public float rotationSpeed = 0.9f;

    private CircleCollider2D gravitationTrigger;

    void Start()
    {
        gravitationTrigger = GetComponents<CircleCollider2D>()[1];
        gravitationTrigger.isTrigger = true;
        gravitationTrigger.radius = gravitationRadius / transform.localScale.x;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        foreach (var objectInVicinity in objectsInRange)
        {
            if (objectInVicinity == null)
            {
                objectsInRange.Remove(objectInVicinity);
                break;
            }
            float dist = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, objectInVicinity.transform.position);
            float gravitationFactor = 1 - dist / gravitationRadius;
            Vector2 force = (transform.position - objectInVicinity.transform.position).normalized * gravitation * gravitationFactor;
            objectInVicinity.AddForce(force * 200);
            objectInVicinity.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().drag = 0.5f;
        }
    }

    private List<Rigidbody2D> objectsInRange = new List<Rigidbody2D>();
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
    {
        var rb = collider.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        if (rb != null)
        {
            objectsInRange.Add(rb);
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collider)
    {
        var rb = collider.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        if (rb != null)
        {
            objectsInRange.Remove(rb);
        }
    }
}
```